# Receive model data inside a CakePHP model callback function

Tags: cakephp, callback, cakephp-2.1, datamodel

I try to use existing model data inside a models callback function in CakePHP 2.1 but can't get it working.
What I do is I try to get a users role in the beforeValidate() callback and check if it's empty. If yes, I'll set it. Normally I do it like this, and for the first creation of the record it works pretty well.

```
if (empty($this->data[$this->alias]['role']))
    $this->data[$this->alias]['role'] = 'user';
```

The problem is, every time an existing record (user) gets updated, the role will be set again.

**Question:** So, how do I check if the field `role` is already set in the record data, not the post data (seems like `$this->data[$this->alias]` only contains POST data)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three solutions to this problem as I can see it.

1. Set a default value in the database column (easiest, best?)
2. Add role to your inputs everytime.
3. Lookup the user and add a role if it's missing

The first two options seem obvious, so I'll just illustrate the last.

```
public function beforeValidate() {
  if (!empty($this->id) {
    $this->data[$this->alias][$this->primaryKey] = $this->id;
  }
  if (!empty($this->data[$this->alias][$this->primaryKey])) {
    // user exists, check their data
    $id = $this->data[$this->alias][$this->primaryKey];
    $user = $this->find('first', array(
      'conditions' => array($this->primaryKey => $id)
    ));
    $this->data[$this->alias]['role'] = $user[$this->alias]['role'];
  }
  if (empty($this->data[$this->alias]['role'])) {
    // new user but missing a role
    $this->data[$this->alias]['role'] = 'user';
  }
  return true;
}
```

This callback will check if an ID was passed, and if so it will look up the user and populate the `role` field. Then, it checks for an empty role and fills it with the default if necessary. Obviously he more code you have, the more possibilities for bugs, so I suggest the first option for default column values.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, that looks like a good and clean solution for this behavior.

Comment: Cool, glad one of the options worked! Remember that the first two will always be the fastest, least (potentially) buggy options.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
if (empty($this->data[$this->alias]['role']) && empty($this->role)) {
   $this->data[$this->alias]['role'] = 'user';
}
```

Comment: I tried that before, except of `$this->id` the fields always return `null`.

And I could image the ID is working because I do `$this->User->id = $id;`in the controller method.